# How to prove the following set is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Assume $ (X,\mathcal{M},\mu) $ is a finite measure space and let $f: X\times[0,1] \to \mathbb{C} $ be a function such that $f(\cdot, y)$ is measurable over X for any $y\in [0,1]$ and $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous over $[0,1]$ for any $x\in X$.

Now, define $$ E_{\varepsilon,\delta}=\left\{ x\in X\thinspace:\thinspace|f\left(x,y\right)-f\left(x,0\right)|<\varepsilon\thinspace \thinspace for \thinspace all \thinspace 
 \thinspace 0<y<\delta\right\}  $$

How can I prove that $E_{\varepsilon,\delta}$ is a measurable set?

I tried to write the set as:

$$ E_{\varepsilon,\delta}=\bigcup_{m>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}\bigcap_{k>\frac{1}{\delta}}\left\{ x\in X\thinspace:\thinspace|f\left(x,y\right)-f\left(x,0\right)|<\frac{1}{m}\thinspace\thinspace\ , 0< y< \frac{1}{k}\right\}  $$

And then to denote $$ g_{y}\left(x\right)=f\left(x,y\right)-f\left(x,0\right) $$

Now for specific $y$ I can write

$$ \left\{ x\in X\thinspace:\thinspace|f\left(x,y\right)-f\left(x,0\right)|<\frac{1}{m}\thinspace\thinspace,\thinspace\thinspace0<y<\frac{1}{k}\right\} =g_{y}^{-1}\left\{ B_{\frac{1}{m}}\left(0\right)\right\}  $$

But I am not sure how to write $E_{\varepsilon,\delta}$ as a countable unions/intersections of such pullbacks, since it has to hold for any $y$ and not only rational $y$

Still trying to figure out how to continue, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous version of this answer was not quite correct. The correct way to write $E_{\varepsilon,\delta}$ would have been
\begin{align}\tag{1}
E_{\varepsilon,\delta}=\bigcap_{0<y<\delta}\;\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\;\big\{x\in X:|f(x,y)-f(x,0)|\le\varepsilon-\frac{1}{n}\big\}
\end{align}
(with the order of $\bigcap\limits_{0<y<\delta}$ and $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}$ reversed). Then however, each $n$ depends on $y$ which is causing problems.

A better solution is one that uses the following

***Lemma.*** *Let $f:(0,\delta)\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function
and $\varepsilon\in\mathbb R\,.$
Then the following are equivalent:*

(i)  *$\quad f(y)<\varepsilon$ for all $y\in(0,\delta)\,;$*

(ii) $\quad$ *For all $m\in\mathbb N$ and all $q\in \mathbb Q\cap(0,\delta)$ there exists an $n\in\mathbb N$
such that*
$$
f(p)<\varepsilon-\frac{1}{m}\;\forall\;p\in\Big(q-\frac{1}{n},q+\frac{1}{n}\Big)\cap\mathbb Q\,.
$$
*Proof.* The implication (i)$\Rightarrow$(ii) follows directly from
the continuity of $f\,.$  For the implication (ii)$\Rightarrow$(i) let
$y\in(0,\delta)$ be arbitrary. There exists a sequence of
rationals $q_i$ that converges to $y$ and satisfies
$$
f(q_i)<\varepsilon-\frac{1}{m}\;\forall\;i\in \mathbb N\,.
$$
By continuity of $f$ we have $f(y)\le \varepsilon-\frac{1}{m}<\varepsilon\,.$
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$
To simplify notation lets write
$$\tag{2}
g(x,y):=|f(x,y)-f(x,0)|\,.
$$
The Lemma shows that we can write the set
$$\tag{3}
E_{\varepsilon,\delta}=\big\{x\in X:g(x,y)<\varepsilon\;\forall\; 0<y<\delta\big\}
$$
as
$$\tag{4}
E_{\varepsilon,\delta}=\bigcap_{m\in N}\;
\bigcap_{\scriptstyle 0<q<\delta\atop\scriptstyle q\in \mathbb Q}\;
\bigcup_{n\in N}\;
\bigcap_{\scriptstyle q-\frac{1}{n}\,<\,p\,<\,q+\frac{1}{n}\atop\scriptstyle p\in \mathbb Q}
\Bigg\{x\in X:g(x,p)\le\varepsilon-\frac{1}{m}\Bigg\}
$$
which is a creation by countable set operations of measurable sets.

- Therefore, $E_{\varepsilon,\delta}$ is measurable.
- To shed some light on these kinds of questions observe that the measurability of a slightly different set

$$\tag{5}
F_{\varepsilon,\delta}=\big\{x\in X:g(x,y)\color{red}{\le}\varepsilon\;\forall\;0<y<\delta\big\}
$$
can be shown more directly:
Since every $g(x,.)$ is continuous the statements
$$\tag{6}
g(x,y)\le\varepsilon\;\forall\; 0<y<\delta
$$
and
$$\tag{7}
g(x,y)\le\varepsilon\;\forall\; 0<y<\delta\,,\;y\in\mathbb Q
$$
are equivalent. This shows that $F_{\varepsilon,\delta}$ can be written as
a countable intersection of measurable sets:
$$\tag{8}
F_{\varepsilon,\delta}=\bigcap_{\scriptstyle 0<y<\delta\atop\scriptstyle y\in \mathbb Q}\big\{x\in X:g(x,y)\le\varepsilon\big\}\,
$$
and is therefore measurable.